# Autodesk Forge WorkItem API: Error: Output is missing [result.pdf]

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm using autodesk Design Automation API to convert DGW to PDF. In Job output file i get this:

```html
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Command: -export Enter file format [Dwf/dwfX/Pdf] <dwfX>_pdf Enter plot area [Current layout/All layouts]<Current Layout>: _all
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Enter file name <visualization_condominium_with_skylight-Layout1.pdf>: result.pdf
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] There were no plottable sheets in the current operation.
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Command: _.quit
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Process exit code: 0
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] End AutoCAD Core Console output
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] End script phase.
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Start upload phase.
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Error: Output is missing [result.pdf].
[10/09/2017 03:01:35] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
```

I've tried two different DWG files (both downloaded from autodesk samples) to no avail.

Here is link to the [DWG File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbpbuwpknuh6ukn/Bottom_plate.dwg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

As this line indicates, this drawing does not have a plottable sheet. This is normally because this drawing has not been activated with any sheet (paper) while the default PDF Export script of Design Automation works for sheet (paper), instead of model space. Note: the command lines of export to PDF are different in Model Space and Paper Space. So, you could simply activate a sheet and upload it to web driver again.

OR, you could create your own Activity to export PDF for Model Space, and invoke the script in the WorkItem.

*There were no plottable sheets in the current operation.*

If you still have the issue, please provide a small sample drawing (after removing confidential information).

Comment: Hi Liang, still facing issues, I'm not AutoCAD savvy. Here is [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbpbuwpknuh6ukn/Bottom_plate.dwg?dl=00) to DWG

Comment: Hi @TarikMakota, sorry, i was not able to respond immediately. May I know how you solved this issue?  after activating one sheet (paper) as what I said, or else?

Comment: Hi, downloaded trial version of Autocad, opened DWG in Autocad, selected "Model" tab then from menu File >Page Setup Manager. Setup the printing instructions there and i was set after that.